# How to set popup menu for ListView header bar together with items popup menu?

Tags: delphi, listview, popupmenu

I have a ListView with `ViewStyle = vsReport` and two popup menus:

1. **Column popup menu**, which I want to open when user right-clicking the header bar
2. **Item popup menu**, must open when the user right-clicking any list item/subitem or whitespace below items.

What is the most correct way to show that menus? Which events should I handle?

The problem is when I set `ListView.PopupMenu` property, the popup menu appearing after right-clicking any point in ListView's client rectangle.

When I handle `ListView.OnColumnRightClick` event, if fires only after clicking on column header, excluding free space of the header bar (on the right of columns).

Event `LisView.OnMouseUp` fires only after right-clicking on whitespace below items.

Comment: Do you want the `PopupMenuItems` menu popup only when you're over an item or even when you're over subitem ?

Comment: @TLama yes, over subitems too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to use the `PopupMenu` property of the listview, leave it unset and you can attach a handler to `OnContextPopup` event and launch whatever popup menu you'd like depending on the position. Example:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  HeaderRect: TRect;
  Pos: TPoint;
begin
  GetWindowRect(ListView_GetHeader(ListView.Handle), HeaderRect);
  Pos := ListView.ClientToScreen(MousePos);
  if PtInRect(HeaderRect, Pos) then
    PopupMenuColumns.Popup(Pos.X, Pos.Y)
  else
    PopupMenuItems.Popup(Pos.X, Pos.Y);
end;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :-) I was copying my test code from the IDE to paste into my answer saying the same thing when the "new answer posted" banner appeared. <g> +1.

Comment: @Ken - I find it strange when that happens on a few hours old question, sorry.. and thanks. :)

Comment: @Sertac, it is strange. I blamed it on my internet connection having a lag today. :-)

Comment: +1 to both. @Andrew, I've left you the comment about `OnContextPopup` but deleted it few minutes later. But anyway, what about the `Handled` parameter ? Shouldn't you set it to True ?

Comment: @TLama - Only if the control has a popup assigned to its 'PopupMenu' and you don't want to have it launched.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly why I mentioned this. It seems that Andrew wants to *override* the assigned popup menu, if there is some.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it considerably. Create your two popup menus (one each for the header row and the columns. Assign the `TListView.PopupMenu` the column popup menu in the IDE.

Use this for the event handler for the ListView:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  HeaderRect: TRect;
  HeaderHeight: Integer;
  Header: HWnd;
begin
  ListView1.PopupMenu := ColumnMenu;   // Default to ColumnMenu
  Header := ListView_GetHeader(ListView1.Handle);
  GetWindowRect(Header, HeaderRect);
  HeaderHeight := HeaderRect.Bottom - HeaderRect.Top;
  if MousePos.Y < HeaderHeight then
    ListView1.PopupMenu := HeaderMenu;
end;
```

It's slightly different than @Sertac's approach, in not calling `ClientToScreen` and `PtInRect` - since we know the point is within the bounds of the ListView, a simple test of the height of the click is sufficient to know if we're in the header or column area. It also ensures that there is always at least one of the popup menus assigned to the `ListView` at all times.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, but I don't like this solution. If you have a better one, please write down, I'll accept it as correct.

```
uses
  CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView.PopupMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
  ListView.PopupMenu.OnPopup := ListViewPopup;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewPopup(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pos: TPoint;
  SrcMenu: TPopupMenu;
  I: Integer;
  MenuItem: TMenuItem;
  Header: HWND;
  HeaderRect: TRect;
  HeaderHeight: Integer;
begin
  // Re-filling ListView's popup menu
  ListView.PopupMenu.Items.Clear();

  // Getting header height
  Header := ListView_GetHeader(ListView.Handle);
  GetWindowRect(Header, HeaderRect);
  HeaderHeight := HeaderRect.Bottom - HeaderRect.Top;
  Pos := ListView.ScreenToClient(ListView.PopupMenu.PopupPoint);

  // Clicked on header?
  if Pos.Y < HeaderHeight then
    SrcMenu := PopupMenuColumns
  else
    SrcMenu := PopupMenuItems;

  // Copying destired menu to ListView.PopupMenu
  for I := 0 to SrcMenu.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    MenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(FListViewPopupMenu);

    with SrcMenu.Items[I] do
    begin
      MenuItem.Action := Action;
      MenuItem.Caption := Caption;
      MenuItem.ShortCut := ShortCut;
      MenuItem.Checked := Checked;
      MenuItem.Enabled := Enabled;
      MenuItem.OnClick := OnClick;
      MenuItem.HelpContext := HelpContext;
      MenuItem.Name := Name;
      MenuItem.ImageIndex := ImageIndex;
    end;

    ListView.PopupMenu.Items.Add(MenuItem);
  end;

  ListView.PopupMenu.Images := SrcMenu.Images;
end;
```

Comment: What don't you like about this solution?

Comment: @NGLN It feels a bit weird, when you need to copy menu items. I thought it is possible to slide down to WinAPI level and do something there.